# Error 404 Web Service NuSoap PHP

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Soy un poco nuevo en los Web Service; estoy diseñando un cliente con `NuSoap` para consumir un Web Service.

Cuando intento consultar la ruta del `wsdl` me arroja un error `404 Not Found`, pero, cuando uso el SoapUI no hay error alguno y me muestra las funciones para poder consultar. Hasta el momento sólo he hecho este pequeño fragmento de código para consultar:

```
<?php  
  include('lib/nusoap.php');
  $url = "http://sultanadv.wi-mobile.com/webservice/server/WSWmForms.wsdl​​";
  $client = new nusoap_client($url);
  print_r($client);
?>
```

Realmente no sé sí estoy haciendo algo mal o me está faltando algo.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

He hecho un cambio en el código y ahora aparece un nuevo error el cual es

> wsdl error: Getting
>   http://sultanadv.wi-mobile.com/webservice/server/WSWmForms.wsdl​​ -
>   HTTP ERROR: Unsupported HTTP response status 404 Not Found
>   (soapclient->response has contents of the response)

Aun no logro que me devuelva al menos una sola respuesta, sólo me devuelve errores.

Comment: Php no tengo ni idea, pero si desde soap funciona entonces es problema del código, tanto soap como el WS los ejecutas lanzas desde la misma máquina no? (Lo digo por si estás en diferente red, vpn, etc...)

Comment: Mi máquina no se encuentra en la misma red que el Web Service. Lo intento consultar por medio del link suministrado. Al momento que ingreso al link me descarga el wsdl

Comment: Claramente, el cliente SOAP está recibiendo un error 404. Mira si estás detrás de un firewall o un proxy transparente que te esté bloqueando por algún motivo. Otra opción, no la óptima, lo sé, es cachear el WSDL en local y lo actualizar de vez en cuando, con un HTTP HEAD para ver si la fecha es más moderna que la versión local.

Answer (score 1):

Que raro, me ha funcionado de esta forma: He instalado NuSOAP usando composer 
`composer require econea/nusoap`
Luego, en la misma carpeta he ejecutado el siguiente código de php 
`php index.php`

```
<?php
  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  $url = "http://sultanadv.wi-mobile.com/webservice/server/WSWmForms.wsdl​​";
  $client = new nusoap_client($url);
  print_r($client);
```

Y me ha funcionado.